# Set div position fixed without page jumping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a modal dialog (jquery.dialog) that opens up when a user clicks on a link. I want to hide the scroll bar on the page behind the dialog, so user will not be able to use it. This works perfectly fine with the overflow:hidden except older IE browsers that mess the entire page up when doing that.

So I came up with this to make it work in the IE: I created a div that was covering the entire content of the page and set it to position:relative and width/height:100%. Then anytime, the modal dialog opens up, the position gets set to fixed. That makes the overwflow:hidden work in old IE.

Now, the other problem came up. When the user is at the bottom of the page and clicks on the links, dialog pops up, but the main page jumps up to the top.

I want the main page to stay intact if possible. How can I do so?

Thank you.

The code to show/close the dialog:

show:

```
$('#allContent').css({ position: "fixed" });

$('#viewJobPanel').dialog('open');

$('#allContent').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

close:

```
$('#allContent').css('overflow', 'visible');
$('#allContent').css({ position: "relative" });
$('#viewJobPanel').dialog('destroy');
```

and when user clicks on the link, I have this event handlers

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Show your code. My best guess is that the page is jumping to the top, because of a hash in the link.

Comment: I added the code to my question

Comment: post the HTML of your links and modal

Comment: I would not remove scrollbars on the page behind the modal, just make the modal follow the user as they scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `span` bound to a click event instead of an anchor element to avoid the default behavior of repositioning the top of the window.